# php_user_filter subclass filter method gets called twice

Tags: php, filter, stream, fread

I am totally befuddled as to why the `filter` function is entered twice: once over the contents of the memory stream, and a second time over nothing (thus while loop never entered). It causes a bug when you actually want to use the stream construct to prepend and append a quoting character.

Program:

```
<?php
class Trivial extends php_user_filter {
    function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing) {
        print("entering filter:\n");

        while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
            print("in the loop\n");
            $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
            stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
        }

        print("returning from filter\n\n");
        return PSFS_PASS_ON;
    }
}

$stream = @fopen("php://temp", 'r+');
fwrite($stream, "Hello", 5);
rewind($stream);
stream_filter_register('trivial', 'Trivial');
stream_filter_append($stream, 'trivial', STREAM_FILTER_READ);
$result = fread($stream, 8192);
print("stream: '" . $result . "'\n");
?>
```

Output:

```
entering filter:
in the loop
returning from filter

entering filter:
returning from filter

stream: 'Hello'
```

*Edit* Checked on PHP7.02 and on my PHP 5.6 on my Mac laptop and Ubuntu 16.04 Linux; this is not a bug or version quirk.

*Edit 2* I think I'm already pretty close to the answer (by very unsatisfying inference though): `$closing` is `false` the first time and `true` the second time.